# Call to undefined function get_current_screen() on my localhost

Tags: theme-development, fatal-error

I'm using Wordpress 3.9.1 and I get the

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen()

if I put the following in my funcitons.php or in any file of my theme:

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
echo $screen;
```

Initially when I got the error, I was working on a theme that I'm creating. However, I tried this with few other themes including TwentyFourteen, and I still got the same error. I even deleted my Wordpress database, created a fresh one and re-installed Wordpress, but still it didn't help.

I checked the `get_current_screen()` function by going to to wp-admin/includes/screen.php and it is there.

I am working on Xampp and I don't have any plugins activated as it is a fresh install. Also in my wp-config.php I haven't changed anything but the 'MySQL settings' (database, username and password) and 'DEBUG mode'.

Any suggestions on how to rectify this?

Comment: Please [edit] more of your code into the question so I can see what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8):

you can try following

```
if ( !function_exists( 'get_current_screen' ) ) { 
   require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/screen.php'; 
} 
$screen = get_current_screen();
echo $screen;
```

Comment: That would include the function, yes, but as the other answer says it won't return any meaningful result (because it's intended to be used in the admin site, and if we were in the admin site then it would already be included).

Answer (score 7):

[`get_current_screen()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) is a backend function and it returns data about the current *backend* administration page. It makes no sense to use this in theme code. The only way it would work (I think but haven't tested) in `functions.php` would be if it were hooked into a backend hook later than `admin_init`.

You don't explain what you are trying to do with `get_current_screen()` but I think you are simply using it incorrectly.

Comment: You are right, however I don't know which hook to use. According to the Codex, admin_init will not work. Also, I'm trying to use this to check whether the new/edit page of a custom post type is being viewed, so that I can set different defaults for the custom meta boxes that I've created. I'm using same code to create meta boxes for multiple post types, using a plugin.

Comment: you need to wrap it in an `is_admin()` check or run it on `admin_init` or another admin only hook

Answer (score 1):

maybe your code run before `admin_init`. Add it to the action:

```php
add_action('admin_init', function(){
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  echo $screen;
});
```